# How can I Enabling the breakpoint margin in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

The Beta 1 of VS 2010 does not seem to have a margin on the left where I can click to add/remove break points with a single click.

I can't find a way to turn this back on. I REALLY hope MS haven't removed this feature in their infinite wisdom!

Anyone know how to get this critical feature back?

Cheers,
Jan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I somehow managed to get the margin removed yesterday. Not sure what happend.

The solution is to go to tools->options->text editor->general and check the box for Indicator margin